# Javers Comparing Lists

Tags: javers

I'm attempting to convert a diff on two lists of Entities into a more human readable format by interpreting container changes (v1.6.0).

If I have a List of Entities (listBefore):

```
  entity1
  entity2
  entity3
  entity4
```

and I reorder the list (listAfter)

```
  entity1
  entity4
  entity2
  entity3
```

The result of comparing these lists using

```
Javers.compareCollections( listBefore, listAfter, Entity.class )
```

is:

```
containerChanges:[(3).removed:'entity4', (1).added:'entity4']
```

From this I can deduce that:  entity4 moved from index 3 to index 1.

If I repeat the same comparison, this time adding a new item to the second list:

```
  entity1
  entity4
  entity2
  entity3
  entity5
```

the result of the comparison is:

```
containerChanges:[(3).'entity4'>>'entity5', (1).added:'entity4']
```

This seems to have missed the fact that 'entity5' was added at index (4) (i.e. not 3) and 'entity4' moved as in the previous example.

Update: I am using the Levenshtein comparator in the above examples.

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

JaVers has two algorithms for comparing lists: Simple and Levenshtein
see http://javers.org/documentation/diff-configuration/#list-algorithms

Simple algorithm is used by default, mostly because its speed. Levenshtein is smarter but could be slow for very large lists. From JaVers doc:

*SIMPLE algorithm generates changes for shifted elements (in case when elements are inserted or removed in the middle of a list). On the contrary, Levenshtein algorithm calculates short and clear change list even in case when elements are shifted. It doesn’t care about index changes for shifted elements.*

My suggestion, try Levenshtein distance algorithm.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - I am using Levenshtein distance algorithm.  That's why in the first example it is ignoring the shift of entity2 and entity3.   The results seems incorrect when I add a new element to the list (second example above).

Comment: Currently, I'm using a custom comparison using the longest increasing subsequence of the two lists.  Any element that isn't part of the subsequence (or an add or remove) is considered a move from one index to another.  The problem is that the framework doesn't support a "Reorder" change type so I need to process this outside of the regular change processing.

Comment: There is no concept of move in JaVers list comparison algorithms. After a move there will be two changes reported: ValueAdded and ValueRemoved, just like you have mentioned.

Comment: In the second example above - there is only an add for entity4 - no remove.  My custom comparator ensures there will always be a matching add/remove pair for anything that moves in the list.